# Changing behavior of pie chart on clik on item legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm working with react and I'm using highcharts,
I'm creating a pie chart with a legend, but when I click in the legend, highcharts hide the corresponding part of the chart, but I wont that Highcharts select this part and the item clicked.
I have tried to change this behavior inserting into this json

```
plotoption{pie {events: {
  legendItemClick: () => {
    alert('Hello world');
  }
}}},
```

but this code doesn't work.

I hope that someone could help me

Bye bye

Comment: I don't know if its a typo or not but `plotoption` should be `plotOptions : `

Comment: I'm sorry, in stackoverflow I wrote plotoption, ma in the json I wrote plotOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pie` series type you need to use `legendItemClick` event as `point` property:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        point: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: () => {
                    alert('Hello world');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3b9f2u0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.point.events.legendItemClick